# How to prevent CXF client service from deadloack?

Tags: multithreading, cxf, deadlock

I'm working on CXF client services but load test (1000 concurrent users) leads to lot's of locked threads and JVM crash. The threads seems to be locked on the Jaxb class AccessorInjector :

```
com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/reflect/opt/AccessorInjector@341F3D78/341F3D84
```

My client is a singleton which is called by a servlet. The client calls the webservice like that :

HttpServlet :

```
SRecherche srech = SRecherche .getInstance();
String reponse = srech.recherche(parametres, retour);
```

Client Service :

```
public static SRecherche getInstance() {
        synchronized (SRecherche .class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new SRecherche();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

.
.
.
.

public String recherche(String parametres, String retour[]) {

    SampleSOAPService sampleSOAPService = new SampleSOAPService(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("service.wsdl"));
    SampleSOAP s = sampleSOAPService .getService();
    ((BindingProvider) s).getRequestContext().put("thread.local.request.context", "true");
    // set the username and password
    ((BindingProvider) s).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
    ((BindingProvider) s).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
    //set timeout to be longer
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(s);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(timeout);
    httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
    httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(timeout);
    httpClientPolicy.setConnection(ConnectionType.CLOSE);
    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
.
.
.

    s.callService(...);
.
.
}
```

I'm working on weblogic 9.2/Java 5.0/CXF 2.5

Do you have any idea about how lot's of simultaneous call of that client may lead to locked threads ?

JDK Version :

```
J2RE 5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 build j9vmap3223-20081129
```

JVM Parameters :

```
-Xjcl:jclscar_23
-Dcom.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path=/usr/java5/jre/bin
-Dsun.boot.library.path=/usr/java5/jre/bin
-Djava.library.path=/usr/java5/jre/bin:/usr/java5/jre/bin:/usr/java5/jre/bin/classic:/usr/java5/jre/bin:/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/bea/patch_weblogic921/profiles/default/native:/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/server/native/aix/ppc:/usr/java5/jre/bin/j9vm:/usr/lib
-Djava.home=/usr/java5/jre
-Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/java5/jre/lib/ext
-Duser.dir=/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/user_projects/domains/rforce
_j2se_j9=70912 0xF12ACF08
vfprintf 0x300017A4
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-Dcom.sun.xml.namespace.QName.useCompatibleSerialVersionUID=1.0
-da
-Dplatform.home=/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2
-Dwls.home=/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/server
-Dwli.home=/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/integration
-Dweblogic.management.discover=true
-Dwlw.iterativeDev=false
-Dwlw.testConsole=false
-Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=
-Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/bea/patch_weblogic921/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath
-Dcom.wily.introscope.agentProfile=/exec/products/weblogic/introscope/wily/IntroscopeAgent_prod.profile
-javaagent:/exec/products/weblogic/introscope/wily/Agent.jar
-Dcom.wily.introscope.agent.agentName=RFORCE
-Dweblogic.Name=RForceServer
-Djava.security.policy=/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/server/lib/weblogic.policy
-Dinvokedviajava
-Djava.class.path=/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/server/lib/geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.3.jar:/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/user_projects/domains/rforce/config/rforce/:/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/user_projects/domains/rforce/config/rforce/wsdl/drakkar/:/usr/java5/lib/tools.jar:/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/server/lib/webservices.jar::/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/common/eval/pointbase/lib/pbclient51.jar:/exec/products/weblogic/v9.2/server/lib/xqrl.jar::
vfprintf
_port_library 0xF12AC748
-Xdump
```

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Not answerable as written. No code, no CXF version, no nothing. You might get better help on the CXF user list.

Answer (score 0):

Just from a quick glance, since you are doing pretty much everything manually (i.e. handling all the connections, etc.) about the only thing I could recommend would be to start a threqad in your public String recherche(String parametres, String retour[]) implementation.

Wrap all the code you have there in an anonymous runnable or Thread instance and kick it off.  The thread will handle all the processing and response to client, leaving the recherche() method free to take another call.

Just a thought.

Also in the way of FYI, the client in what you describe above would actually be the Servlet, as it is making the call to the service.  Or in other words, it looks like the Servlet is the consumer and the singleton is the provider.